# Text-align not working and footbar div not appearing?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to fix the top and bottom div bars on scroll with the text centred

Top bar is fixed but text align isn't working
Bottom bar isn't appearing at all

I can't see what is wrong with the css, I get no errors in the dev console in chrome

Thanks

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>
My test
</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">  
</head>
<style>

div{ margin-left: 20%;
padding-left: 20%
}

#headbar 
{display:inline;text-align:center;position:fixed;width:100%;
}
#footbar 
{display:block;text-align:center;position:fixed;width:100%;
}
#width: 80%


p:nth-child(3n) {width:80px; background: #e0ffff};
p:nth-child(3n+1) {background: #f5f5db};
p:nth-child(3n+2) {background: #ffe4e1};


<body>


</style>


<div id="headbar" style="background-color: #ffccff";> 

    <a href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/news" target=_blank>BBC news</a>  
    <a href="http://www.theguardian.com/uk" target=_blank>The Guardian</a> 

</div>

<?php


for ($n=0; $n<101; $n++) {
    $modulo = ($n%3);

    if($modulo==0){
        $bg_color = '#e0ffff';
    }elseif($modulo==1){
        $bg_color = '#f5f5db';
    }elseif($modulo==2){
        $bg_color = '#ffe4e1';
    }

    echo '<p style="margin-left:20px; margin-right:20px; background-color:'.$bg_color.';"> Paragraph...'.$n.'</p>';
}






?>

<div id="footbar" style="background-color: #ffff66";>
<form>
<input type="button" onclick="location.href='http://www.facebook.com';" value="Facebook" />

<input type="button" onclick="location.href='http://www.instagram.com';" value="Instagram" /> 
</div>



</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why is your closing `<style>` tag wrapping your opening `<body>` tag as well??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```css
#headbar 
{
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:center;
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
}
#footbar 
{
  display:block;
  text-align:center;
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  bottom:0;
}


p:nth-child(3n) {width:80px; background: #e0ffff};
p:nth-child(3n+1) {background: #f5f5db};
p:nth-child(3n+2) {background: #ffe4e1};
```

```html
<div id="headbar" style="background-color: #ffccff";> 

    <a href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/news" target=_blank>BBC news</a>  
    <a href="http://www.theguardian.com/uk" target=_blank>The Guardian</a> 

</div>


<div id="footbar" style="background-color: #ffff66";>

<input type="button" onclick="location.href='http://www.facebook.com';" value="Facebook" />

<input type="button" onclick="location.href='http://www.instagram.com';" value="Instagram" /> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, just tired this on and both bars appear but both text is appearing on the right side of the screen with a left margin for both bars

Comment: Yes I saw that too, that's why I removed the padding and margin. You still want to keep that?

Comment: Ahhh I see the issue now, I need the paragraphs to have that left and right margin but nothing else

Answer (score 0):

```
<title>
My test
</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">  
</head>
<style>

body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.spacer{
    height:1em;
    width:100%;
}
#headbar{display:inline;text-align:center;position:fixed;width:100%;
}

#footbar 
{display:block;text-align:center;position:fixed;width:100%;bottom:0;
}
#width: 80%
p:nth-child(3n) {width:80px; background: #e0ffff};
p:nth-child(3n+1) {background: #f5f5db};
p:nth-child(3n+2) {background: #ffe4e1};


</style>
<body>

<div id="headbar" style="background-color: #ffccff";> 

    <a href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/news" target=_blank>BBC news</a>  
    <a href="http://www.theguardian.com/uk" target=_blank>The Guardian</a> 

</div>

<?php


for ($n=0; $n<101; $n++) {
    $modulo = ($n%3);

    if($modulo==0){
        $bg_color = '#e0ffff';
    }elseif($modulo==1){
        $bg_color = '#f5f5db';
    }elseif($modulo==2){
        $bg_color = '#ffe4e1';
    }

    echo '<p style="margin-left:20px; margin-right:20px; background-color:'.$bg_color.';"> Paragraph...'.$n.'</p>';
}






?>
<div class="spacer"></div>
<div id="footbar" style="background-color: #ffff66";>
<form>
<input type="button" onclick="location.href='http://www.facebook.com';" value="Facebook" />

<input type="button" onclick="location.href='http://www.instagram.com';" value="Instagram" /> 
</div>



</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I try to correct some issues. your text align is not working because of `<div>` padding and margin. hope this helps.

here is a screenshot how it seems on my screen

http://prntscr.com/a794gf